# Can the hypotenuse in the right angle triangle be put this way?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In right side triangles we know:

- $x = z\cos(θ)\quad\Rightarrow\quad z = x\sec(θ)$
- $y = z\sin(θ)\quad\Rightarrow\quad z = y\csc(θ)$

So

$$\frac{z}{2}=\frac{1}{2} x\sec(θ)=\frac{1}2 y\csc(θ)$$
If each of them equal half $z$ would adding them together give me z?

$$z = \frac{1}2x\sec(θ) + \frac{1}2y\csc(θ)$$

Can $z$ (hypotenuse) be put this way? And if not where did I go wrong?

Comment: yes, It seems ok

Comment: Please edit the question and write what $x,y,z,\theta$ variables are.